# Can I set constant value after declaration?

Tags: c++, constants, declaration

Can I set constant value after declaration in C++? I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    const int a;
    a = 56;
    cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

It sucesfully compiled but output in console was 4309678.

Comment: Which compiler compiled this?

Comment: GNU GCC Compiler is name of the compiler in settings.

Comment: @jaksia [Doesn't compile here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f2a5d7ee7932c3c8)

Comment: [Not 4.4.7](https://godbolt.org/g/1YjWRc) and I highly doubt anything newer.

Comment: `a` is declared as `const` , compiler won't allow it to modify by `a = 56;`

Comment: Nor  does GCC 5.1.0.

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and add output of `g++ --version`. (Platform would be nice as well.)

Comment: To add upon @Scheff s request, exact compiler flags also please.

Comment: When I didn’t used:
cout << a;
return 0;
but only return a; return was 56.

Comment: A `const` variable should get its value during initialization. Assigning to it later is UB and a straight up bug.

Comment: "When I didn’t used: cout << a; return 0; but only return a; return was 56." - just because something compiles (and/or runs) does *not* make it correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't. Furthermore that will not even compile. You need to initialize the `const` value:

```
const int a = 56;
```

or:

```
const int a{ 56 };
```

After that you can't assign a new value to a variable, as [const](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) marks it read-only so this will not compile:

```
const int a = 56;
a = 57; // error: assignment of read-only variable 'a'
```

Leaving the constant uninitialized will yield the following error if on GCC:

```
error: uninitialized const 'a' [-fpermissive]
```

or if using Visual C++:

```
const variable "a" requires an initializer
```

Comment: Is const int a{ 56 }; in anything diferent from const int a = 56;?

Comment: @jaksia There is no difference as you are using the built in type `int`.